# Is the limit $\lim_{x \to 1} \frac{\sin (1-x)}{\sqrt{x}-1}$ solved correctly?

Tags: calculus, limits, solution-verification

Can you please check if i solved this limit correctly?$$\lim_{x \to 1} \frac{\sin (1-x)}{\sqrt{x}-1}$$

To skip writing of code , I will just explain what I did. First, I multiplied the expression by $\frac{\sqrt{x}+1}{\sqrt{x}+1}$.
Then I got$$\frac{(\sin (1-x)) (\sqrt{x}+1)}{x-1}.$$

Next I pulled out the minus in from of the brackets in  denominator, so I got$$\frac{(\sin (1-x)) (\sqrt{x}+1)}{-(1-x)} .$$Since $\frac{\sin{(1-x)}}{1-x}$ is equal to 1, I am left with $ -(\sqrt{x}+1)$. After exchanging $x$ with $1$, I got $-2$ as a result. Did I do this correctly?

Comment: I think it is correct.

Comment: It is correct for sure

Comment: One note: $\frac{\sin{(1-x)}}{1-x} \ne{1}$ but $\lim\limits_{n\rightarrow\infty}\frac{\sin{(1-x)}}{1-x}=1$.

Comment: Yea, sorry, I'm new to limits so i forget to write it xD. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Applying L'Hospital (L'H), we get:

$$\lim_{x\to 1}\frac{\sin(1-x)}{\sqrt x-1}\stackrel{L'H}=\lim_{x\to 1}\frac{-\cos(1-x)}{\frac{1}{2\sqrt x}}=\frac{-1}{\frac{1}{2}}=-2$$

The above makes it sure you got the correct result in your development and that this last was very probably correct.

Comment: I would have applied the rule but i didn't do derivatives yet and Wikipedia says that it has something to do with derivatives :D

Answer (score 2):

$$\lim_{x \to 1} \frac{\sin{(1-x)}}{\sqrt{x}-1}$$

$$=\lim_{x \to 1} \frac{\sin (1-x)(\sqrt x+1)}{x-1}$$

Putting $h=1-x,$ so $h\to 0$ as $x\to 1,$
$$=-\lim_{h \to 0} \frac{\sin h(\sqrt {1-h}+1)}h$$

$$=-\lim_{h \to 0} \frac{\sin h}h \cdot  \lim_{h \to 0}(\sqrt {1-h}+1)$$

$=-1\cdot 2=-2$